# How to merge cached data which are different field but same query in Apollo-React?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

My first Query was :

```
const krxStockCloseQuery = gql`
    query getKrxStock($code: String!, $start: String, $end: String){
        krxStock(code: $code, start:$start, end:$end){
            date
            close
        }
    }
`;
```

And cached data was:

```
▾ROOT_QUERY
krxStock({"code":"005930","start":"2020-12-13"}):
0:{"date":"2020-12-14","close":73800}
1:{"date":"2020-12-15","close":73800}
2:{"date":"2020-12-18","close":73000}
```

Then, My second query was ( field changed: close -> volume ):

```
const krxStockVolumeQuery = gql`
    query getKrxStock($code: String!, $start: String, $end: String){
        krxStock(code: $code, start:$start, end:$end){
            date
            volume
        }
    }
`;
```

And then all of the cached data was changed:

```
▾ROOT_QUERY
krxStock({"code":"005930","start":"2020-12-13"}):
0:{"date":"2020-12-14","volume":21510415}
1:{"date":"2020-12-15","volume":20863671}
2:{"date":"2020-12-18","volume":17380940}
```

How can I set Cache like below?

```
▾ROOT_QUERY
krxStock({"code":"005930","start":"2020-12-13"}):
0:{"date":"2020-12-14","close":73800,"volume":21510415}
1:{"date":"2020-12-15","close":73800,"volume":20863671}
2:{"date":"2020-12-18","close":73000,"volume":17380940}
```

Comment: no type of entries defined, no id fields ... how can it be recognized as the same ??

Comment: Can I use 'date' field as 'id'??

Comment: it's not hard to find https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#customizing-identifier-generation-by-type

Comment: then, how could I merge those caches?